# How to clock_gettime within clock_getime?

Tags: c++, performance, time

Lets say I want to measure the total time of a particular function. Now this function calls other functions (f1 and f2). So I want to calculate total time of f1 and f2.

What I was expecting was `f total time = f1 total time + f2 total time`

```
void f(){
    struct timespec total_start, total_end;
    struct timespec f1_start, f1_end;
    struct timespec f2_start, f2_end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &total_start);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &f1_start);
        f1();
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &f1_end);

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &f2_start);
        f2();
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &f2_end);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &total_end);

    f_total_time = (total_end.tv_sec - total_start.tv_sec) + (total_end.tv_nsec - total_start.tv_nsec)/1e9 ;

    f1_total_time = (f1_end.tv_sec - f1_start.tv_sec) + (f1_end.tv_nsec - f1_start.tv_nsec)/1e9 ;

    f2_total_time = (f2_end.tv_sec - f2_start.tv_sec) + (f2_end.tv_nsec - f2_start.tv_nsec)/1e9 ;
}
```

My question is, Is this a correct way to measure time of functions inside function.

Problem : The problem I am facing is total time of f1 and f2 does not add up to total time of f. ie `f total time != f1 total time + f2 total time` what actually happens is `f total time > f1 total time + f2 total time`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It takes a little time to call `clock_gettime`, so it's natural for the total time to exceed the times for the individual function calls.  Nothing wrong.  If you want to avoid that, just add the function times yourself: *after* calculating the function times, `f_total_time = f1_total_time + f2_total_time;`.

Comment: Are you using c++?

Comment: No that is correct but calling `clock_gettime` takes time!

Comment: @TonyD I get that but `f total time greater then  f1 total time + f2 total time by factor of 100 , eg: 0.38 > 0.01 + 0.03`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes c++11

Comment: and compiling in -03

Comment: You could reduce the overhead a bit cutting out one of the `clock_gettime()` calls between the two function calls (you only need one).  Ultimately however, you need to understand that overall elapsed time of an execution of function `f()` is more than the sum of the elapsed times of `f1()` and `f2()`.  The added instrumentation (calls to `clock_gettime()`) exacerbate that, but it would still be true without them.

Comment: Any reason you add a tag for a different, unrelated language? Don't spam tags!

Comment: @pokche You may be interested in [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

Comment: @Olaf I should I have used just `c`, `performace`, `time`  and not `c++`? since clock_gettime is a `c` thing

Comment: "yes c++11" - so it is clearly C++ code!

Comment: I tried and get coherent results...

Comment: Regarding the 0.38 > 0.01 + 0.01 example - does it happen consistently?  If very infrequently, it might have been that your process was swapped off CPU during the `clock_gettime` calls.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès hmm ok then may be I am doing something stupid. Will let you know soon :/

Comment: You may test returned values of calls to `clock_gettime`. Function can fail.

Comment: Please add your measurement results.  If durations are smaller or similar to how long it takes to read the Posix REALTIME clock, you may be trying to measure an inch-long-board with a yard-long-stick.  consider putting a sleep of known size into each of f1() and f2(), for a test.

Answer (score 0):

To chronometer a C++ application, note initial time in a variable, and a declare a duration (seconds) :

```
#include "time.h"
clock_t t (clock ());
size_t duration (0);
```

during execution, duration is updated this way :

```
duration = (clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer -

Yes. IMHO it appears to be a valid duration measurement technique
of a function within a function.

The Posix clock_gettime() reports sec/nanoseconds from a fixed
time, so each access is independent of any other.

From   "man clock_gettime" :

*All implementations support the system-wide real-time clock,
   which is identified by CLOCK_REALTIME.  Its time represents
   seconds and nanoseconds since the Epoch.  When its time is
   changed, timers for a relative interval are unaffected, but
   timers for an absolute point in time are affected.*

I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Perhaps you need to know more about the relative duration of your
code vs duration of the clock read mechanisms you are using.

---

On my Ubuntu 15.10, on an older Dell, using g++ 5.2.1, the Posix
call

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)
```

uses > 1,500 ns (avg over 3 seconds) (i.e. ~1.5 us)

To achieve some measure of repeatability, the duration you are
trying to measure (f1() and f2() and f1()+f2()) must be more than
this, probably by a factor of 10.

Your system will be different (than mine), so you must test it to
know how long these clock reads take.

There is also the interesting idea of knowing how fast
CLOCK_REALTIME increments.  Even though the API indicates
nanoseconds, it might not be that fast.

---

An alternative I use is std::time(nullptr) with a cost of ~5 ns (on my system), 3 orders of magnitude less.  FYI: ::time(0) measures the same.

A loop controlled by this API return simply kicks out at the end
of a second, when the value returned has changed from previous
values.  I usually accumulate 3 seconds of loops (i.e. a fixed
test time) and compute the average event duration.

Example measurement output:

```
751.1412070 M  'std::time(nullptr) duration' invocations in 3.999,788 sec   (3999788 us)
187.7952549 M  'std::time(nullptr) duration' events per second
5.324948176 n seconds per 'std::time(nullptr) duration' event
```

If using this clock access, you can simply subtract 5.3 ns (on my
system) from each invocation when calculating the seconds per event for
your functions.

---

Note: Any Posix API is an interface to a system provided
function, not the function itself.

Being part of an API is not conclusive evidence about the
functions implementation ... which may be in any language,
even assy for peak performance.

Comment: I just noticed you are using "CLOCK_MONOTONIC".  I have only used CLOCK_REALTIME.  I think the issue I've noted and the 10x idea is still valid.